# How can I submit an input value with a post request in React?

Tags: reactjs, input, axios, handle, rest

I am trying to post request a starting date, end date, and the number of guests in my program. The post request for the start date and end date works. However, I am having problems with submitting the input value for the number of guests. My number of guests value returns as undefined in the console.
Most likely I am making a mistake with my handle submit but I don't know how I can solve this problem. Can somebody help me with this problem ?

```
function Search() {
    const history = useHistory();
    const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());
    const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState(new Date());

    const [numberOfGuests, setNumberOfGuests] = useState();
  
    const selectionRange = {
      startDate: startDate,
      endDate: endDate,
      key: "selection"
    };

    const handleSubmit = event => {
      setNumberOfGuests(event.numberOfGuests);
      event.preventDefault()
    }
  
    function handleSelect(ranges) {
      setStartDate(ranges.selection.startDate);
      setEndDate(ranges.selection.endDate);
    }

    const onSearch = useCallback(() => {
      console.log("startDate: ", startDate);
      console.log("endDate: ", endDate);
      console.log("numberOfGuests", numberOfGuests);
    
      axios
        .post(`/availableapartments`, {
          startDate,
          endDate,
          numberOfGuests
        })
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(res);
          console.log(res.data);
          history.push('/availableapartments')
        }); 

    }, [startDate, endDate, numberOfGuests]);
  
    return (
      <div className="datepickersearch">
        <DateRangePicker ranges={[selectionRange]} onChange={handleSelect} />
  
        <h2> Number of guests</h2>
        <input min={0} defaultValue={2} max={7} type="number" event={[numberOfGuests]} onChange={handleSubmit} />
        <Button onClick={onSearch}>Search Apartments</Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
  
  export default Search;
```

Comment: I think it meant to be ```setNumberOfGuests(event.target.value);```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*input* elements do not accept  neither `event` nor `defaultValue` attributes as seen in your code, see https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp for reference *React DOM* sticks to native DOM API.

In React you can let the state control your *input* by adding a `value` attribute to it which refers to your state:

```
<input
  min={0}
  max={7}
  value={numberOfGuests}
  //  etc..
/>
```

In addition you need to add a change handler to be able to modify the state:

```
<input
  value={numberOfGuests}
  onChange={handleNumberOfGuestChange}
/>
```

```
const handleNumberOfGuestChange = (event) => setNumberOfGuests(event.target.value);
```

You might want to read the official docs which explains this very well and will give you everything you need to get you started with React https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

Comment: Thank you for your help ! This solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

change your handlesubit method to

```
const handleSubmit = event => {
      setNumberOfGuests(event.target.value);
      event.preventDefault()
    }
```

your event `event` value is containing inside target.value
use `event.target.value` to access data